# openSSL tutorial not fully working - Can sign but cannot restore original file

Tags: linux, openssl, digital-signature

I'm writing, and testing, a little tutorial for my groupmates involved in an openSSL homework. We have a bunch of PDF files, I'm the CA and each one should send me a signed PDF for me to be verified.

I've told them to do the following (and tried to do it by myself)

- Request and obtain a certificate (I'll skip this part)
- Create a MIME message with the PDF file in it `makemime -c "text/pdf" -a "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=”Elaborato.pdf" Elaborato.pdf > Elaborato.pdf.msg`
- Sign with openSSL `openssl smime -sign -in Elaborato.pdf.msg -out Elaborato.pdf.p7m -certfile ca.pem -certfile nomegruppo.crt -inkey nomegruppo.key -signer nomegruppo.crt`
- Verify with `openssl smime -verify -in Elaborato.pdf.p7m  -out Elaborato-verified.msg -CAfile ca.pem -signer nomegruppo.crt`
- Extract attachment with `munpack Elaborato-verified.msg`
- View with Acrobat Reader

The problem is that even if I get a file that (from its binary content) resembles a PDF file my current Ubuntu PDF viewer doesn't read it. The `XXXElaborato.pdf` extracted by munpack is a little bit smaller than the original.

**What's the problem with this procedure**? In theory, they should send me the signed S/MIME message and I should be able to read the PDF within it. **Why can't I restore the original content of the PDF file**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `text/pdf` MIME type is wrong. It should be `application/pdf` and, by the way, I used `mpack` instead of makemime.

That makes the tutorial for signing a document work